# Simplifying an IF/ELSE in Facebook API Script

Tags: javascript, facebook, if-statement, facebook-opengraph

I fear this question probably has a simple answer, but boy have I laboured in
vain to find it!  Any help would be appreciated.  We've got our Facebook App
all set up nice and our Actions and Objects work great with a little Java
script.  BUT... I want to streamline the whole flow of our site by getting rid
of the Alert dialogues in the Javascript that triggers the action.

This is what we've got now (which works):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function postResonate_with_cambodia()
{
    FB.api('/me/onemandala:resonate_with' +
            '?intention=http://1mandala.org/1action-002','post ',
            function(response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
            if (confirm('You are not yet signed up for 1Mandala. 1Mandala uses Facebook Connect to     showcase the amazing 1Actions folks are taking on our platform. We will redirect you now to the signup page...')) { window.location.href='http://www.1mandala.org/app-signup ' } else { void('') };;
            } else {
            if (confirm('You are resonating with the intention for 1SewingKit Cambodian Orphanage Empowerment. We will take you now to the project page to take action...')) {  window.location.href='http://1mandala.org/1action-002 ' } else { void('') };;
            }
            });
}
</script>
```

The dialogues should make it pretty clear how that is supposed to work.
BUT... wouldn't it be so much better if instead of those dialogues, the script
either sent the visitor direct to the Facebook Signup Dialogue, OR to the
landing page?  Here's my attempt that doesn't work. :-(  Any suggestions would
be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function postResonate_with_cambodia()
{
FB.api('/me/onemandala:resonate_with' +
'?intention=http://1mandala.org/1action-002','post',
function(response) {
if (!response || response.error)
{window.location.href='http://www.sign-up-page.com' } ;
} else {
{ window.location.href='http://1mandala.org/app-1action-002' } ;
}
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". What does or doesn't it do? Are you getting any errors? Are you checking the browser's console for them?

Comment: Thanks, good question.  The error I get on the Firefox debugger is "ReferenceError: postResonate_with_cambodia is not defined @ http://1mandala.org/app:1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simple, you've got a syntax error. That's the reason for `ReferenceError: postResonate_with_cambodia is not defined`, yet the syntax problem should've been reported too.

You've got a closing brace too much (or an opening one too less); also you don't need to wrap your else-body in two blocks. One is enough, and for a one-liner you even don't need that. Corrected:

```
function postResonate_with_cambodia() {
    var url = '/me/onemandala:resonate_with?intention=http://1mandala.org/1action-002';
    FB.api(url, 'post', function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            window.location.href='http://www.sign-up-page.com';
        } else {
            window.location.href='http://1mandala.org/app-1action-002';
        }
    });
}
```

Always indent your code properly. And use semicolons after single statements, not after blocks.

Comment: WOW!  That's it!  I had a feeling that it had something to do with a simple syntax oversight.  Thank you so much for your correction.  The revised script now takes 1 step or 3 steps out of the from the flow of our site.  Hopefully this can help others simplify there use of Open Graph Actions too.  As Steve Jobs says "Simplicity is the highest form of sophistication".  Thanks again!  --- the script is in operation here:  www.1mandala.org/app